# Hive How to limit the number of entries in collect_set

Tags: hive, hiveql

Let's say I have a table that contains two columns:

```
Category Productname
Cat1     prod1
Cat1     prod2
Cat1     prod3
Cat1     prod4
Cat1     prod5
Cat2     prod6
Cat2     prod7
Cat2     prod8
```

Now if I do something like:

```
SELECT Category, collect_set(Productname)
FROM myTable;
```

I would get something like:

```
Cat1    [prod1...prod5]
Cat2    [prod6...prod8]
```

Now, there are 5 products in Cat1 and 3 in Cat2. However, I want to limit the number of products in each category. Let's say the upper limit is 3. The 3 products can be any random ones as long as they belong to the same category. Also, the upper limit can be a large number. It's worth noting that I want the collect_set to stop once it has reached the upper threshold. Because generating the output and then perform the filtering can be expensive. Methods other than collect_set are also welcome. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by a combination of window function and collect_set.Partition by category and get <= 3 rows for each category,product combination and then use collect_set on the subset.

```
select category, collect_set(productname)
from 
(
    select category,productname, row_number() over (partition by category) as r_no
    from table_name
) a
where a.r_no <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify why you want to do a group by category inside the from(..)a clause. Seems to me that you should do that outside the from(..)a clause.

Comment: Also my table already has a partition of date string. I tried your query it does not give correct output. Can you suggest how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: So once I add row_number() over (partition by category) as row_no, the output is messed up. I am wondering if it's because the table is already partitioned on some other column when I create the table. Can you clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output? What do you get when you execute just select category,productname, row_number() over (partition by category) as row_no
    from table_name. The solution is to assign a row_number to each row of category,productname and get all rows that are less than 3 rownumber.This is give a subset of category,productname and then apply collect_set

Comment: I get something like: x�u�ے�@E+���"���T���. If i just do a select category,productname from table_name. I would get the category and productname as expected.